# Mysql random item from a set of items

Tags: php, mysql

I want to update my table with a random pre-defined item that i pick from  a comma delimited list like

```
UPDATE the_temp SET the_temp.the_temp_status=randStr('x','y','z');
```

`randStr` is not a native mysql function,so that don't work.Php has a similar function `echo $items[array_rand($items)];`.

Is there a function in mysql that can help in picking a value from a list like i have explained?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can just use `ELT` and `FLOOR` .just put what you will random and use this

```
   select id, 
  ELT(FLOOR(1 + (RAND() * (50-1))), 'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m ','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y', 'z',
 'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M ','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y', 'Z' ) as ranomdstring
 from table1
```

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ecec5/1)

For just your case a b c use this

```
   select id, 
     ELT(FLOOR(1 + (RAND() * (4-1))), 'a','b','c') as ranomdstring
   from table1
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/abd66/23)

---

**Here the update case**

```
UPDATE the_temp 
SET the_temp.the_temp_status=ELT(FLOOR(1 + (RAND() * (4-1))), 'a','b','c');
```

Comment: I used it in update like `UPDATE the_temp SET the_temp.the_temp_status=ELT(FLOOR(1 + (RAND() * (4-1))), 'a','b','c');` which is good enough for what i am doing.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No, as far as I am aware there is not. However, could you not do this in the host language? Most languages I know of today have a function for picking a random item out of a list, and if they don't, you can simply generate a random index into the list.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a mysql function for it. You could create you own function for it but I think the easiest way is just to generate the query with PHP

```
$randStr = $items[array_rand($items)];
$query = "UPDATE the_temp SET the_temp.the_temp_status=" . $randStr;
```